# Calculate length of user input to prevent overflow when outputting in div

Tags: php

I am reading a string my user is inputting via PHP and I need to spit it back out in a div tag. This div tag has a width of 500px. If the user enters a word that is too long, the word will overflow the container. If the user enters two words that are almost two long, it will split into two lines.

My question is how do I determine if a word is too long or not? I have tried setting a character count, which is not an accurate representation of length as certain characters (ie W and I) have different widths. Is there a solution?

My current algorithm is to break the user input into chunks, each of 40 characters, and output it.

Comment: This should be done client side with CSS3 using the `word-wrap` property.

Comment: To be done properly, this needs to be handled on the client side, not the server side. Look into styling changes with CSS.

Comment: @Supericy Thank you. That worked perfectly. Can you write as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: you could use [imagettfbbox](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) to calculate the width of the word respecting different character sizes (if you are certain about the font's family & size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to still implement your character count mechanism you can; you just need to make sure your text is mono-spaced (same width). To do this you can just add `<pre></pre>` around your text block; this can also be accomplished with `<code></code>` and `<tt></tt>` but if you want a simple CSS solution you could use.

```
<style>
.myclass { word-wrap:break-word; }
</style>
<p class="myclass">some text</p>
```

Comment: `word-wrap` was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Usually you shouldn't use PHP for things like that. Try CSS instead:

```
.break { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

will do the trick

Answer (score -2):

you can simply break-up words that are larger than, say, 20 characters - into chunks, using the <wbr> tag. Here's some more info: http://motyar.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/tell-browser-they-may-break-your.html

Comment: You still have to specify the position of the tag, this solution is not suited here